# Python mocking delete

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I practice TDD but I have not used mocking before.

Suppose I want to build a function that should create a folder, but only if that folder does not already exist. As part of my TDD cycle I first want to create a test to see that my function won’t delete an already existing folder.

As my function will probably use os.rm, I gather I could use mocking to see whether os.rm has been called or not. But this isn’t very satisfactory as there are many ways to delete folders. What if I change my function later on to use shutil.rmtree? os.rm would not have been called, but perhaps the function now incorrectly removes the folder.

Is it possible to use mocking in a way which is insensitive to the method? (without actually creating files on my machine and seeing whether they are deleted or not - what I have been doing until now)

Comment: I am not sure whether tests for side-effects are part of TDD methodology - I see TDD as testing for what the code is supposed to do rather than what it is **not** supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 options:

1. You wrap the deletion in a function, e.g., `delete_folder`; in the tests, you mock the function and check whether it has been called.
2. You use [pyfakefs](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs) to mock the entire filesystem. I haven't used it yet, but it seems to be very powerful.

Comment: Option #1 has same disadvantages as mocking os.rm - it is easy not to call self-defined function (to pass the test) by calling `shutil.rmtree()` directly (to have the side-effect Daniel is trying to avoid).

Answer (score 0):

The problem of "mockism" is that tests bind your code to a particular implementation. Once you have decided to test for a particular function call you have to call (or not as in your example) that function in your production code.

As you have already noticed, there is plenty of ways to remove the directory (even by running `rm -rf` as external process).

I think the way you are doing it already is the best - you check for an actual side-effect you are interested, no matter how it has been generated.
If you are wondering about performance, you may try to make that test optional, and run it less frequently than the rest of your test suite.